# Install Nuget Package in UWP

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package, nuget-server

I want to add SQLitePCL package in my UWP project. ( It is already installed in one another UWP project.)

But now I am trying to browse the package and it shows an error.

**[nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  Unable to connect to the remote server
  A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 185.82.212.95:8080**

What can I do? My internet connection is perfectly working.

I also Downloaded this package manually (sqlitepcl.3.8.7.2.nupkg) But I don't know how and where to add and install this package to add it to my project.

Comment: There are a number of possible solutions here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2880

Answer (score 0):

Go to

Settings ( Global Settings of your PC ) > Network and Internet > Proxy > Automatic Proxy Setup > and set Automatically detect settings to off.

This Works for me.....

Comment: Could you please mark it as accepted to convenient people who visit this later? Thanks for understanding.